# How to locate the button element using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am having issues locating button and clicking on it. It is pop up in internet explorer. I am using by classname but don't work.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget").click()
```

HTML:

[image: button class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget"type="button">Accept</button>]

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: You've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute this content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)) which may be useful to a broader audience.

Answer (score 0):

To locate and click the element with text as **Accept** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ui-dialog-buttonset>button.ui-button.ui-corner-all.ui-widget"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']//button[@class='ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget' and text()='Accept']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```